# Dualboot Windows 10 and Fedora 24 with UEFI on HP Desktop

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I have an HP Envy [700-109c](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03962180) that I am trying to dualboot with Fedora 24. The computer originally came with Windows 8 (which I down(up?)graded to Win7). I have performed a clean install of Windows 10 from a flashdrive image. Now I would like to install Fedora 24 alongside it. IN the past I had this computer running well with Windows 7 and Fedora. However, it was a real pain to circumvent the UEFI with Windows 7. Now that I'm on Windows 10, I figured I'd try installing both in UEFI mode since Fedora supposedly supports it. However, after installing Fedora on a second partition and restarting the computer and booting into Windows, the grub bootloader seems to be overwritten with the Microsoft bootloader.

Here's the steps I've thusfar taken:

- Go into the BIOS and reset the default settings
- convert drive from mbr to gpt
- Install Windows 10 from the flashdrive image
- Shrink the partition down 500GB for Fedora
- Create a LiveUSB image of Fedora and boot into it
- Install Fedora using the installer defaults on the free 500GB.

Upon the first boot (and every subsequent boot thereafter) into Fedora everything seems to work fine. I get the option to boot into Fedora, the Fedora recovery, and the Windows Boot Manager. However, the instant I decide to boot into the Windows Boot Manager, grub is removed and I can no longer get to Fedora; it'll boot straight into Windows from then on until I re-install Fedora again and the cycle repeats.

I should note that, the reason I'm reinstalling Fedora and Windows in the first place is because (after having successfully upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10 without corrupting the bootloader via the upgrade tool) Windows decided to perform an automatic update which then overwrote the bootloader and screwed up the dualboot.

Answer (score 0):

Have tou tried disabling fast boot in Windows 10?

http://mywindowshub.com/how-to-turn-on-or-off-fast-startup-in-windows-10/

As I understands the fast boot option is like a mini hybernation step that in some dual boot cases, prevent the machine to recognize other OS until Windows fully shutdowns and restart.